# How to update initstate's value's array using useState?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I Want to update categories array's value/ insert categories json data into  after fetching categories from DB.
But can't find the right way ?
Note: Please check the loadCategories function.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {getCategories} from "../../../Functions/Categoy";

const initialState = {
    title:"",
    desc:"",
    colors:["Black", "Brown", "Silver", "White", "Blue"],
    categories:[] // here to insert
}

const CreateProducts = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([initialState]);

    const { title, desc, colors, categories } = data
  
    useEffect(() => {
        loadCategories();
    }, [])
  
    const loadCategories = () => {
        getCategories()
                .then((res) => {
                    // here I want to insert/update categories value
                    // setData({ prevState =>  [...prevState, categories : res.data] })
                })
    };

    return (
          <div>{JSON.stringify(categories)}</div>
)}

export default CreateProducts;
```

Comment: Is state going to hold anything else eventually, or just a category array?

Comment: @Andy yes. I edit that sections and please check it out.

Comment: The state looks like its only referring to one product, is that right? One product with lot of categories.

Comment: yes and I'm creating dynamic form in react. Actually i'm looking for a solution in loadcategories where I update categories in setData.

Comment: I would go with @Andy's solution as that seems to be correct and what I also would suggest doing, though I am not sure why you think it wouldn't work. If "creating dynamic form" is relevant to your question/issue and you aren't simply needing to update the nested `categories` array like you ask in your post then please update your question to include all the necessary and relevant code and context/details for the *actual* problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @DrewReese I agree. There's a lot more going on that probably needs refactoring (not OP's fault). But sometimes you get a sense that things would better a different way, but because we're only seeing part of the picture we can only just answer the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Categoy" is probably a typo? It should be "Category".
2. No need to add `initialState` in an array to `useState`.
3. [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) makes life a little less complicated when working with data returned by [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). You can add an async function to `useEffect` and have that fetch your data, parse it, and then update your component state.
4. You can then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the categories in state (or whatever you want to do) to produce your JSX.

An updated example.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {getCategories} from '../../../Functions/Category';

const initialState = {
    title: '',
    desc: '',
    colors: ['Black', 'Brown', 'Silver', 'White', 'Blue'],
    categories: []
};

function CreateProducts() {

  const [data, setData] = useState(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadCategories() {
      const res = await getCategories();
      const categories = await res.json();
      setCategories({ ...data, categories });
    }
    loadCategories();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {data.categories.map(category => <div>{category}</div>)}
    </div>
  );

}

export default CreateProducts;
```

Comment: I got your point but I'm creating dynamic form. So I did `const [data, setData] = useState([initialState]);` and want to update categories in loadCategories function. something like this way `setData( [...data, categories : res.data] )`

Comment: In that case [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Have a parent component deal with the state, and have it pass down all the data the "dumb" components need along with handlers to update that state.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {getCategories} from "../../../Functions/Categoy";

const initialState = []

const CreateProducts = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState(initialState);

    useEffect(() => {
        loadCategories();
    }, [])

    const loadCategories = () => {
        getCategories()
            .then((res) => {
                 setData([...data,...res.data])
            })
      };

      return (
           <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
      )}

export default CreateProducts;
```

Comment: You're not parsing the JSON anywhere.

Comment: please check my code again. Actually there's more value in initialState.